# LDAP authentication fails on ripple and actual device but not on browser

Tags: ionic-framework, openldap, ripple

I'm trying to get an authorization token for an **Ionic App** from a LDAP service in a remote server.

**I can get the auth token** when I run the Ionic App in the **browser** with the command ionic serve and when I use **Postman**,

**BUT** it takes lot of time and eventually **fails** when I debug using **ripple** for the App or when I test on the phone or **tablet**.

---

The error says:

- status: 503
- statusText: Service Unavailable
- data: html code from http://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html

---

```js
var deferred = $q.defer();
       
var req = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://host:port/adap?bind=token',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Basic <username>:<password>'
  }
};

$http( req )
.then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
    deferred.resolve(data.data);
})
.catch(function(data) {
    console.error(data.data);
    deferred.reject(err);
});

return deferred.promise;
```

Does anybody have some hint about this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you say the service is available, so the problem must be in the app side.

Check IP tables, and check **ripple's proxy** and set it to *none*.

Comment: Thanks for those hints!
Setting ripple´s proxy to none allowed it to use the service.
That service is indeed in development, I don´t have access to the server but I know now that it´s filtering IPs, and the WIFI was using another IP than the one allowed, and that´s why it didn´t work on the device.